# how to concatenate dynamic value in nested sql statement in java?

Tags: java, sql

I have this code:

```
long userID = user.getId();
String query = "select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where     userclient.userid = " +
        "(select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = "+userID+")";
```

I want to use userID as part of the query in the Where clause,but I seem to be not concatenating userID(I want it it to be read as a dynamic value,and not a String)properly.Could anybody give some guidance on doing it?

EDIT:
This is the full source code:

```
public ArrayList<Post> retrieveFollowerDB(String userName){
    ArrayList<Post> postArray = new ArrayList<Post>();
    ArrayList<Integer> intArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ResultSet rs = null;
    Connection conn = null;
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;

    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    try {
        User user = twitter.showUser(userName);
        long userID = user.getId();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TwitterException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String query = "select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where userclient.userid = " +
            "(select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = ?)";
    System.out.println(query);

    String userNames = null;
    String query1 = null;
    try{
        JDBC db = new JDBC();
        conn = db.getConnection();
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setLong(1, userID);
        rs = pstmt.executeQuery();

        Properties config = new Properties();
        config.load(new FileInputStream("C:/Users/L31207/Desktop/FYPJ/OpenCalais/MarcusFYPJ/categories.properties"));
        String[][] categories = fetchArrayFromPropFile("content", config);
        HashMap<String,Integer> hashmap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
        for (String[] mapping : categories)
        {
            hashmap.put(mapping[0], 0);

        }

        while(rs.next()){
            int id = rs.getInt("followerid");
            userNames = rs.getString("username");
            intArray.add(id);
        }   

        ResultSet rs1 = null;
        Connection conn1 = null;
        PreparedStatement pstmt1 = null;

            for(int i=0;i<intArray.size();i++){
                query1 = "Select post.content from twitter_content.post where post.userid = "+intArray.get(i)+"";
                JDBC db1 = new JDBC();
                conn1 = db1.getConnection();
                pstmt1 = conn1.prepareStatement(query1);
                rs1 = pstmt1.executeQuery();
            }
                while(rs1.next()){
                    Post post = new Post(rs.getString(userNames), rs.getString("content"), hashmap);
                    System.out.println(rs.getString("content"));
                    postArray.add(post);
                    System.out.println(postArray.size());
                }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
    return postArray;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use Prepared Statement to inject the values for variables.

```
con = DriverManager.getConnection("...");
String query = "select userclient.username from twitter_content.userclient where     userclient.userid = (select follower.followerid from twitter_content.follower where follower.followerid = userclient.userid and follower.userid = ?)";
PreparedStatement prest = con.prepareStatement(sql);
prest.setLong(1,<user_id>);
ResultSet rs1 = prest.executeQuery();
```

Comment: My mistake since your userId is long you should be using setLong. I have updated the answer take a look

Comment: I noticed the typo,but it does not work.Anyway I edited the post above with the source code.

Comment: What's the exception did you get and on what line?

Comment: Just java.lang.NullPointerException,the console did not point out any line number.

Comment: Null pointer could be possibly be in the following lines: 
conn = db.getConnection();
pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
Probably, you are failing to create a connection. I would suggest debugging the issue or printing the entire stack trace.

Comment: I tried debugging the codes,but it does not stop at those lines.I personally think it was caused by the wildcard in the sql statement,since it does not specify any particular value in the Where clause.

Comment: Well if you are receiving null pointer then, its probably not related to the prepared statement. Its some where you are trying to access a null object

Comment: The only place I suspect could get a null value is the line: long userID = user.getId();, but it returns the correct value.Seems that I am in a dead end.

Comment: If you are using MySQL you could print the query using pstmt.toString(). If you are using something else I would suggest adding log4JDBC to log the sql query.

Comment: I resolved the issue already,just that there is another error I had to fix.Thank you for trying to help anyway.